# Fixed height text input field, text on top

Tags: html, css

I have a text input field with a fixed height, I want the box to look big because of the considerable amount of text that has to be typed in it. The problem is, when the height is set and the user clicks in the box, the text starts right at the center of the box, I would like the text to start on top. My code:

```css
#mainText {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>

    <input type="text" id="mainText" value="Your text">
    <button>Submit Text</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: use a **textarea** instead of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an input type called `textarea`. It's better for large amounts of text. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Example usage:

```
<textarea id="mainText" name="mainText">Your text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  textarea instead of input which will allow you to enter multiple lines and it will start writting from top left